# Array_sum in php - all values

Tags: php

I wanna sum all values from my array
for example

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message_count": 14051
    },
    {
      "message_count": 12731
    },
    {
      "message_count": 7867
    },
    {
      "message_count": 6053
    },
    {
      "message_count": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

and that's my code:

```
<?php
$messages_count = file_get_contents('baza.html');
$json_a=json_decode($messages_count,true);
$counting_base = ($json_a['data']);
echo array_sum($counting_base);
?>
```

but I still get '0'. Any ideas?
Thank you very much

Comment: add the output of $counting_base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your array is two-dimensional. `array_sum()` requires a one-dimensional array. To make it one-dimensional, loop through the array, and use `array_sum()`, like so:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($json_a['data'] as $key => $innerArr) {
    $new[] = $innerArr['message_count'];
}

echo array_sum($new); // 40706
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/107824)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
array_sum(array_column($json_a['data'], 'message_count'));
```

Output: `40706`

[live demo](https://eval.in/107828)

**alternative:**

You can do it by a loop:

```
array_sum()
```

will not be working since you do not right formated array(1D array).

```
$sum = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($counting_base); $i++)
{
    $sum += $counting_base['message_count']; 
}

echo "Total = ". $sum;
```

Comment: @user2527983: see my top answer